# formatting all the markers for the hovering series in a HighCharts scatterplot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, formatting, hover, scatter-plot

I want to change the appearange of all the markers (not only the one pointed) when hovering the series, but the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/fw852fy9/4/) does not work properly. What's wrong?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter'
        },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        lineWidth:1,
              states: {
                  hover: {
                      lineWidthPlus: 2,
            marker: {
              enabled: true,
              radius:3,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  fillColor:'#FF0000',
                  lineColor:'#00FF00',
                  lineWidth:3,
                  radius:12
                }
              }
            }  
                  }
              },
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius:3,
          states: {
                  hover: {
              fillColor:'#FF0000',
              lineColor:'#00FF00',
              lineWidth:3,
              radius:12
              }
          }
        }
      }  
    },
    series: [{
      data: [[29.9, 71.5], [106.4, 129.2], [144.0, 176.0], [135.6, 148.5], [216.4, 194.1], [95.6, 54.4]]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover state works only for the point which is hovered. If you want to set all the markers to be hovered, you need to change their state programmatically, e.g. on series mouseover/mouseout.

```
  series: [{
 stickyTracking: false,
events: {
  mouseOver: function() {
    this.data.forEach(p => p.setState('hover'))
  },
  mouseOut: function() {
    this.data.forEach(p => p.setState())
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/0zu9jmca/

Comment: Wow. That's an elegant solution.