# alternative way to change hovered series and its points properties in a HighCharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, updates

I have a line chart with a lot of series and I need to change the color of the hovered series and all its points.

A suggested approach is to use mouseOver and mouseOut events, and inside them run a `.update` method [for the series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575870/highcharts-how-to-change-line-color-when-hovering-a-scatterplot-series) and `.setState` method [for all its points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979218/formatting-all-the-markers-for-the-hovering-series-in-a-highcharts-scatterplot).

Unfortunately in my case this solution turns out to be laggy, so I've tried to avoid it.

I was able to change the color of the series without using .update methods, setting `this.graph.stroke` property, but I was unable to find a corresponding changeable property for its points: `.graphic.stroke` property seems to not be the right one (I've navigated through the series and points object through Firefox Developer tools).

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ept3gkLv/2/) relevant code:

```
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
              originalColor = this.color;
              this.graph.stroke="rgb(255,0,0)";
              this.points.forEach(p => p.graphic.stroke="rgb(255,0,0)}");
              //this.data.forEach(p => p.setState('hover'))
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
              this.graph.stroke=originalColor;
              this.points.forEach(p => p.graphic.stroke=originalColor);
              //this.data.forEach(p => p.setState())
            }
        }
    },
},
```

P.S.: the commented lines work but with a lot of series and points they run more slowly than `this.graph.stroke=...` so the change for points color appears not synchronized with that of series line.

So, my question is: which property of `series.points` can I access to change the color immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable series `states` and use `attr` method to change `stroke` and `fill` colors:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            },
            inactive: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
                this.graph.attr({
                    stroke: "rgb(255,0,0)"
                });
                this.points.forEach(p => p.graphic.attr({
                    fill: "rgb(255,0,0)"
                }));
            },
            mouseOut: function() {
                this.graph.attr({
                    stroke: this.color
                });
                this.points.forEach(p => p.graphic.attr({
                    fill: this.color
                }));
            }
        }
    },
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dnr93Law/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.states

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know how I can access `dataLabels` in the same way? `this.dataLabels.forEach` does not work.

Comment: Hi @tic, You can access `dataLabels` through points: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r573kqbf/

Comment: Sorry, I've used the word access but I did mean write. How can I set the dataLabel color?

Comment: Please see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933474/change-datalabels-color-in-a-highcharts-chart-when-hovering-without-updating-the

Comment: Hi @tic, You can change `dataLabels` color in similar way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/myqpfs0L/