# access svg element in a arearange HighCharts chart

Tags: svg, highcharts

The last line of the following code (brutally copied from a HighCharts demo chart page) changes the opacity of a `arearange` series:

```
var chart=Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Range',
        data: ranges,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
});

chart.series[1].update({fillOpacity:0.7},true);
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wn6qhma7/1/).

(the opacity could be set directly inside the chart object, but I need to modify it after the chart creation, the code is a toy example to simulate my needs)

My real chart has several `arearange` series, and updating them is heavy. Is there a way to modify such property avoiding the `.update` method? that it, is there a way to directly access the `svg` element corresponding to the `arearange` series?

I've tried to check the series `.graph` property, as previously suggested in an answer to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884521/alternative-way-to-change-hovered-series-and-its-points-properties-in-a-highchar) question, but in this case `arearange` series has no `.graph` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done exactly the same as in the answer mentioned in your question but instead of modifying the `graph` you have to modify the `area` property.

**Code:**

```
  chart.series[1].area.attr({
    fill: 'rgba(124,181,236,0.7)'
  });
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/abohcq4x/